# Pose grab/move breaks the model

Tags: animation, armature, pose-mode

Hi I'm trying to create an animation
rotations works fine in pose mode and I can do every thing
but if I use grab/move the models breaks! any tip?
PS: I need to do animations for games with unity3d
[image: move breaking model]

Comment: The solution is, don't translate those bones.  Is there something you wanted to achieve by moving them?

Comment: Yeah put the leg forward since I have to create a sword attack animation. I wanted to save time

Comment: Rotate the leg, or look up how to set up "inverse kinematics".

Comment: Is there a premade model rig that I can use to make animations?

Comment: you can look into rigify, or download any number of rigged models; blendswap.org might be a good place to look.  Rigs need to be adjusted to the proportions of the model using them.  Really, you should just learn how to rig-- it shouldn't take more than an hour to learn how to make a simple rig.

Comment: I am trying do animate a VRM rigged model :/